# How can I scan NFC-Tags with iOS / Xamarin from viewmodel

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nfc

I have a Cross-Platform Xamarin.Forms .net standard app for android / iOS and wanted to add the nfc-scan functionality.

For my first test, I've put all into my *AppDelegate* class.
**This code works:**

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, INFCNdefReaderSessionDelegate
{
    public NFCNdefReaderSession Session { get; set; }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        if (Session == null)
        {
            Session = new NFCNdefReaderSession(this, null, true);
        }
        Session = new NFCNdefReaderSession(this, null, true);
        Session?.BeginSession();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    public void DidInvalidate(NFCNdefReaderSession session, NSError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceToolStandard DidInvalidate: " + error.ToString());
    }

    public void DidDetect(NFCNdefReaderSession session, NFCNdefMessage[] messages)
    {
        var bytes = messages[0].Records[0].Payload.Skip(3).ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceToolStandard DidDetect: " + message);
    }
}
```

### **My Problem:**

After that I've put all into a new *NfcScanner* class and wanted to call the *ScanAsync* function from my ViewModel. If I run this code, everything looks fine. The scan starts when I press the button on my phone, it shows the blue tick symbol but then **it never gets into one of the implemented methods *DidDetect*, *DidInvalidate*. Do you know what the reason could be?**

```
public class NfcScanner : INfcScanner, INFCNdefReaderSessionDelegate
{
    public string ErrorText { get; private set; }

    private NFCNdefReaderSession _session;
    private TaskCompletionSource<string> _tcs;

    public Task<string> ScanAsync()
    {
        if (!NFCNdefReaderSession.ReadingAvailable)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Reading NDEF is not available");
        }

        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        _session = new NFCNdefReaderSession(this, null, true);
        _session.BeginSession();

        return _tcs.Task;
    }

    public void DidInvalidate(NFCNdefReaderSession session, NSError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceToolStandard DidInvalidate: " + error.ToString());
        _tcs.TrySetException(new Exception(error?.LocalizedFailureReason));
    }

    public void DidDetect(NFCNdefReaderSession session, NFCNdefMessage[] messages)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceToolStandard DidDetect msgs " + messages.Length);
        var bytes = messages[0].Records[0].Payload.Skip(3).ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceToolStandard DidDetect msg " + message);
        _tcs.SetResult(message);
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceToolStandard Dispose");
    }
}
```

I tried also to make a void *Scan()* Method and call it directly from *AppDelegate*. The result is the same. The scan window opens and it shows the blue tick symbol, but it never reaches the methods diddetect, didinvalidate.

---

### **Edit 07.02.2018 16:56:**

I saw in the example code, that their class derives from UITableViewController.
This was the only real difference between my code and the example code. After I derived in my *NfcScanner* class from *ViewController* it worked. But I'm not sure why and if it's the right way?

```
public class NfcScanner : UIViewController, INfcScanner, INFCNdefReaderSessionDelegate
{
 ...
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/poz1/NFCForms have you take a look to this?

Comment: Hi @Alessandro Caliaro, thanks for your comment. I looked at your link and I think it's only for android and windows phone? For Android I already have a working solution. I'm now trying to implement the function on iOS. Is it possible, that the INFCNdefReaderSessionDelegate interface works only in the AppDelegate? Perhaps this could be the reason...

Comment: you are right, it's not for iOS... sorry..

Comment: Check the [Configuration](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios11/corenfc/) , and you can try [this sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios11/NFCTagReader/) first to test if it works.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT Thanks for your input. The Configuration should be correct. Because scanning from the AppDelegate works. I'll give it a try, this example looks like what I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro no problem! thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to find an answer, why it works after i derived from *UIViewController*. I think I found it, in this tutorial: [Core NFC Tutorial](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-nfc-tutorial-for-nfc-on-ios-devices/)

> Creating a session, we can specify a delegate in our
>   NFCNDEFReaderSession class. I would like to use the NFCHelper class as
>   the delegate, so we must first adhere to the delegate protocol,
>   NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate. **This delegate is based on an Objective-C
>   object, so we must first also adhere to NSObject.**
>   NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate has two delegate methods we must
>   implement:

*UIViewController* inherits from *NSObject*. Now it also works after I changed my code to:

```
public class NfcScanner : NSObject, INfcScanner, INFCNdefReaderSessionDelegate
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Pfff, I spent almost a day with the same issue and finally found this post. This solved my issue too

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit old and still comes up on top of the search results so I just wanted to share a new answer for any one looking for it. In order to access any of the NFC Functionality, you can use the Plugin.NFC nuget package. It supports writing to NFC Tags using iOS too, and also provides a great sample in the GitHub repository. You should be able to use that straight from your View
Model if you really need to, though I would recommend calling it from your view instead, based on MVVM principles.

I recently used it and documented my journey on [How to get started with NFC and Xamarin in 5 minutes](https://medium.com/@prototypemakers/start-building-with-nfc-rfid-tags-on-ios-android-using-xamarin-today-2268cf86d3b4?sk=f0cb84c6ae3fdf500f9a2926821b7a84).

Comment: Hi man, I've seen you in several threads so I wanted to ask. Can you read and send data from iOS to some desktop NFC reader/writer (if it has HCE)? Can you do this without Apple Wallet and any hidden charges?

Comment: @YasserJarouf message me on LinkedIn or Twitter, you can find links on my profile! I have several questions to make sure I answer your question right, iOS doesn’t support HCE, but some android devices do. But if another device/desktop has HCE, you should be able to read using your iOS